# jQuery autocomplete from php-json without database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, autocomplete

I want to make `autocomplete` on my form with `jQuery`. The source taken from `json` data from php, but i don't use database.
Here is my code :

**facebookfriends.php**

```
<?php
include('facebookdata.php');

$user_friend = $user_friends['data'];

$json_friends = json_encode($user_friend);
echo $json_friends;
?>
```

**Script**

```
$(function() {
  $( "#search" ).autocomplete(
  {
     source:'facebookfriends.php',
  });
});
```

**JSON DATA**

```
[{"name":"Indiarto Priadi","id":"502163984"},
 {"name":"Agustin Kertawijaya","id":"511990261"},
 {"name":"Jecklyne Christin L","id":"528197912"},
 {"name":"Jazi Eko Istiyanto","id":"531149275"},
 {"name":"Esritha Situmorang","id":"535864892"},
 {"name":"Christy Margaretha Siregar","id":"543468540"},
 {"name":"Daniel Oscar Baskoro","id":"549332828"},
 ........]
```

I just want to display the `name` in autocomplete to ensure that the autocomplete works well. But it doesn't. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: tell me what's your issue. kindly explain clearly

Comment: the autocomplete does not appear (nothing happens when I type some letter in input fields)

Comment: Autocomplete needs either an array of strings (without keys), or an array with keys of `label` and/or `value` - http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source. Can you update `facebookdata.php` to add a `label` key, which could just be a copy of your `name` value.

Answer (score 1):

1.You have to parse json in php
2.make an array for dropdown list

Following steps to be followed:

```
     $data ='[{"name":"Indiarto Priadi","id":"502163984"},
              {"name":"Agustin Kertawijaya","id":"511990261"},
              {"name":"Jecklyne Christin L","id":"528197912"}, 
              {"name":"Jazi Eko Istiyanto","id":"531149275"},
              {"name":"Esritha Situmorang","id":"535864892"},
              {"name":"Christy Margaretha Siregar","id":"543468540"},
              {"name":"Daniel Oscar Baskoro","id":"549332828"}]';
    $user_friend =  json_decode($data, true );
    $data=array();
    foreach($user_friend as $key=>$val)
            $data[]=$val['name'];
    $json_friends =json_encode($data);
    echo $json_friends;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass label and value into you php file

For example

```
    $data[] = array(
                'label' =>  $row['city_name'].','.$state['state_name'].','.$c_name['country_name'],
                'value' =>  $row['city_name'].','.$state['state_name'].','.$c_name['country_name']
                    );

echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```